# How to do static code analysis with HipHop for PHP?

Tags: php, static-analysis, hiphop

I have installed hiphop on Ubuntu following these inscrutions : https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages-on-Ubuntu-12.04

Now how do I do static code analysis on a single/multilple php files with this?

Comment: hhvm --hphp --target hhbc --input-list /tmp/files.list --output-file hhvm.hhbc.sq3

Answer (score 2):

You might find [hphpa](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/hphpa) useful. This is a convenience wrapper for HipHop's static analyzer.

Comment: I only get an error, even with hhvm installed: `./hhvm-wrapper.phar analyze ./

hhvm-wrapper 2.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Using ruleset phar://hhvm-wrapper-2.0.3.phar/ruleset.xml

HHVM failed to process the files.
`